# How to apply a background to a DIV, but keep child image background transparent

Tags: css, image, html, background

I want a div as my header with a centred image and a background colour, but I don’t want the background colour to show through the image.

html:

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="home.html"><img id="headerpic" src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#header {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
}
#headerpic {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Please help D:

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you're wanting here.  What does the image look like?

Comment: If your PNG image has an alpha chanel (transparency), then any background color from the parent element (header) will show through...

Comment: its just text over a transparent background, that’s why the colour shows through. I need a way to cancel this.

Answer (score 1):

Do not give the div any opacity , that will be inherited by child elements. Instead define its background color in RGBA palette.That way the "opaque" effect is not given forth to child elements.

EDIT : 
In your case it would look like this:

```
#header {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

As you can see , you define color and opacity ( thats the A in rgbA , it stands for alpha ) , but it is only applied to the specified selector , while opacity is inherited down the DOM tree.

Comment: This didn't do what I wanted, but still looks pretty cool. What I essentially want are two blocks of bg colour that automatically adjust to the pages width, and the centred image, like this; [block][image][block]

Comment: I thought giving the parent div a background colour would do this, but it hasn't worked as I expected.

Comment: My apologies , but it is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. If you could explain with different wording maybe we could come up with better answers